# DevOps can't find the APPSETTINGS.JSON file - but the project deploys and runs as expected

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-devops, appsettings, npm-scripts

We have a React application embedded within an ASP .NET Core web application - I believe the react.js template was used to create the project.

Within the `clientapp` folder, we maintain an `appsettings.json` file to hold the URL for the API.

[image]
[image]

We use Git for Version Control, and Azure DevOps houses the repository. CD/CI is implemented and a pipeline is in place to build and deploy/release to Deployment Slots.

Once deployed, the application runs fine in the DEV Deployment slot - the react app can read the API URL correctly - the DEV API URL is currently hardcoded within the `appsettings.json` file.

We're looking to use transformation to manage the state of the API URL within file `appsettings.json`. However once deployed, DevOps cannot find the file `appsettings.json`, so they cannot apply the transformation.

Developers have little to no access to the PipeLine, making it difficult to determine if a step or process in the Build Pipeline manipulates the `appsettings.json` file.  Further, we understand that webpack is not being utilized.

We have no access to the Azure Portal Console - we can't look for the file.

During the publish portion of the Build PipeLine, I see the following: `react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build`

And below it the following output:

```
  Creating an optimized production build...
  Compiled successfully.

  File sizes after gzip:

    1.47 MB    build\static\js\2.ef7d60da.chunk.js
    268.58 KB  build\static\css\2.24993e46.chunk.css
    19.18 KB   build\static\js\main.878c95b4.chunk.js
    5.63 KB    build\static\css\main.0044b53f.chunk.css
    775 B      build\static\js\runtime~main.ff579d2d.js
```

I suspect the `appsettings.json` file is being stored into one of the JS files, but I'm not really sure.

If the file is being migrated into one of the above files, how can we exclude `appsettings.json` from the Optimization process?

And if Optimization process isn't the reason `appsettings.json` "disappears", where else can I look to figure out why it isn't being deployed/released as a discrete file?

Comment: *I suspect the APPSETTINGS.JSON file is being stored into one of the JS files, but I'm not really sure.* Why? That seems incredibly unlikely.

Comment: `appsettings.json` has no bearing on React, it is part of the .NET Core application. You're looking at the wrong thing. How is your .NET Core application being built and published?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, "has no bearing on React". The React application reads from this file. I've also found in a CHUNK.JS file, the following fragment after running the Optimization step on my machine: **function(e){e.exports=JSON.parse('{"apiendpoint":"https://bidsapi-dev...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the `npm run --max_old_space_size=4096 build` command on my machine and found created, a similar set of files:
[image]

And I found the `appsettings.json` elements embedded in one of them:
[image]

I also see from the picture above that yes we ARE using some flavor of WEBPACK, and that explains for me why `appsettings.json` isn't deployed as a discrete file.

It would still be of value to me knowing how to exclude `appsettings.json` from the Build Optimization process - or knowing if that's even possible.